# Google maps not displaying properly in phonegap

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api's for displaying maps in my phonegap application.

When map is loaded i am getting issue like below:

Map is not loaded properly in div. Only some portion of map is displayed.

[image]

I have used below code to show map:

Html is:

```
<div id="mapOuterDiv_details" class="mapHolder">
     <div id="map_details">
      </div>
</div>
```

I am loading map in  with id "map_details".

I have given 100% width and 100% height for both div.

and javascript code is:

```
var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.997779,73.789684),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_details"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.997779,73.789684),
                                            map: map,
                                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                                            });


        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Thanks in advance,
Tejas

Comment: This worked for me....
// Call resize function to load div properly after loading map
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
                                      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          });

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to use my plugin phonegap-googlemaps-plugin? https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

You can run Google Maps SDKs on Android and iOS, and control it from JavaScript easily.
[image]

Comment: Thanks wf9a5m75 for your effort. Below solution works for me: google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() { google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); });